# Did the Buddha teach how to discern deception?

Tags: pali-canon

With deception as rampant as ever, what did the Buddha teach about it -- other than "let none deceive another" in the metta sutta -- especially how to discern and respond to deception?

Answer (score 3):

Our first duty is to give up deception ourselves:

> [SNp2.9:5.1](https://suttacentral.net/snp2.9/en/sujato#snp2.9:5.1): Giving up mirth, prayer, weeping, ill will,
> [SNp2.9:5.2](https://suttacentral.net/snp2.9/en/sujato#snp2.9:5.2): **deception**, fraud, greed, conceit,
> [SNp2.9:5.3](https://suttacentral.net/snp2.9/en/sujato#snp2.9:5.3): aggression, crudeness, stains, and indulgence,
> [SNp2.9:5.4](https://suttacentral.net/snp2.9/en/sujato#snp2.9:5.4): they’d wander free of vanity, steadfast.

To give up deception ourselves, we must understand wrong view and right view. Believing in worng view is deception.

> [MN117:5.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:5.1): And what is wrong view?
> [MN117:5.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:5.2): ‘There’s no meaning in giving, sacrifice, or offerings. There’s no fruit or result of good and bad deeds. There’s no afterlife. There are no duties to mother and father. No beings are reborn spontaneously. And there’s no ascetic or brahmin who is well attained and practiced, and who describes the afterlife after realizing it with their own insight.’

Giving up wrong view, we focus on right view:

> [MN117:6.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:6.1): And what is right view?
> [MN117:6.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:6.2): Right view is twofold, I say.
> [MN117:6.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:6.3): There is right view that is accompanied by defilements, has the attributes of good deeds, and ripens in attachment.
> [MN117:6.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:6.4): And there is right view that is noble, undefiled, transcendent, a factor of the path.
> [MN117:7.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:7.1): And what is right view that is accompanied by defilements, has the attributes of good deeds, and ripens in attachment?
> [MN117:7.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:7.2): ‘There is meaning in giving, sacrifice, and offerings. There are fruits and results of good and bad deeds. There is an afterlife. There are duties to mother and father. There are beings reborn spontaneously. And there are ascetics and brahmins who are well attained and practiced, and who describe the afterlife after realizing it with their own insight.’
> [MN117:7.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:7.3): This is right view that is accompanied by defilements, has the attributes of good deeds, and ripens in attachment.
> [MN117:8.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:8.1): And what is right view that is noble, undefiled, transcendent, a factor of the path?
> [MN117:8.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:8.2): It’s the wisdom—the faculty of wisdom, the power of wisdom, the awakening factor of investigation of principles, and right view as a factor of the path—in one of noble mind and undefiled mind, who possesses the noble path and develops the noble path.
> [MN117:8.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:8.3): This is called right view that is noble, undefiled, transcendent, a factor of the path.
> [MN117:9.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:9.1): They make an effort to give up wrong view and embrace right view: that’s their right effort.
> [MN117:9.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/sujato#mn117:9.2): Mindfully they give up wrong view and take up right view: that’s their right mindfulness.

So we have a long way to go before dealing with deception in others. Our own deceptions trip us up and we need to give up those deceptions before we can reliably detect and respond to deception in others. It takes a while to understand ourselves and others. It takes a while to become a good friend among good friends.

> [SN3.18:4.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn3.18/en/sujato#sn3.18:4.3): Good friends, companions, and associates are the whole of the spiritual life.

Comment: Nice answer Oya<3

Comment: Right view will definitely help with discerning deception! Thanks